# call server function in server tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

can i call my function inside my server tag?

```
public string Mytext()
{
}
```

And

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="Mytext()"><asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"><%=Mytext()%><asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using [Expression syntax](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickstartV20/aspnet/doc/pages/syntax.aspx), e.g.,

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="<%$ Mytext() %>"><asp:Label>
```

Comment: can i put function in another class?

Comment: <%$ (new MyClass()).Mytext() %> or <%$ MyClass.Mytext() %> Put using namespace in code behind file

Comment: @hungryMind i get this error : The expression '<%$ MyClass.MyText() %>' is invalid. Expressions use the syntax <%$ prefix:value %>.

Comment: Sorry gave you wrong info. Not sure, if you can run Text="<%$ Mytext() %>" code. If you do, use your class inside method MyTest() or you can build your expression. See an example http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022509-1.aspx

Comment: Yes, this link is better than mine.